# Blender 2.90 crashing on rendering animation with smoke?

Tags: rendering, animation

I am trying to render a simple scene with some little smoke on the progress bar to allow the emission show better, upon rendering it closes, when I remove the smoke and attempt to render everything is fine. When I am in rendered mode in the viewport with the smoke every thing is still fine but when I click `Render > Render Animation` to render with the smoke present it just closes. the smoke simulation is from (**80-160**)s the entire animation is (**0-220**)s

[image]

> Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-7500U 
> GeForce 940MX